# Akka HTTP streaming API with cycles never completes

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I'm building an application where I take a request from a user, call a REST API to get back some data, then based on that response, make another HTTP call and so on.  Basically, I'm processing a tree of data where each node in the tree requires me to recursively call this API, like this:

```
     A
    / \
   B   C
  / \   \
 D   E   F
```

I'm using Akka HTTP with Akka Streams to build the application, so I'm using it's streaming API, like this:

```scala
val httpFlow = Http().cachedConnection(host = "localhost")
val flow = GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
   import GraphDSL.Implicits._

   val merge = b.add(Merge[Data](2))
   val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[ResponseData](2))

   takeUserData ~> merge ~> createRequest ~> httpFlow ~> processResponse ~> bcast
                   merge <~         extractSubtree                       <~ bcast

   FlowShape(takeUserData.in, bcast.out(1))
}
```

I understand that the best way to handle recursion in an Akka Streams application is to handle recursion outside of the stream, but since I'm recursively calling the HTTP flow to get each subtree of data, I wanted to make sure that the flow was properly backpressured in case the API becomes overloaded.

The problem is that this stream never completes.  If I hook it up to a simple source like this:

```scala
val source = Source.single(data)
val sink = Sink.seq[ResponseData]

source.via(flow).runWith(sink)
```

It prints out that it's processing all the data in the tree and then stops printing anything, just idling forever.

I read [the documentation about cycles](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html) and the suggestion was to put a `MergePreferred` in there, but that didn't seem to help.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459329/why-akka-streams-cycle-doesnt-end-in-this-graph) helped, but I don't understand why `MergePreferred` wouldn't stop the deadlock, since unlike their example, the elements are removed from the stream at each level of the tree.

Why doesn't `MergePreferred` avoid the deadlock, and is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Where in your stream are you printing that all the data in the tree is being processed?  (e.g., before or after the processing?)

Comment: In processResponse, there's a println statement and I can see all the data elements printed.

Comment: So every element gets processed, it's just that the stream doesn't complete?  Are you using `eagerComplete = true` in the `MergePreferred`?

Comment: Correct, all the elements get processed, it's just the stream doesn't complete.  If I use `eagerComplete = true` in `MergePreferred` the stream completes, but only elements that are not fed back into the loop get printed (in other words, elements from the root of the tree get printed, not the next level down)

Comment: When it comes to a solution, is it a requirement that (if processing multiple trees), an entire tree rooted at `A` gets processed/emitted before a tree rooted at, say, `G` (with `G` not being a child of `A`)?

Comment: Yes, that is a requirement.  We might be processing multiple trees at once depending on the load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MergePreferred` (in the absence of `eagerComplete` being true) will complete when all the inputs have completed, which tends to generally be true of stages in Akka Streams (completion flows down from the start).

So that implies that the merge can't propagate completion until both the input and `extractSubtree` signal completion.  `extractSubtree` won't signal completion (most likely, without knowing the stages in that flow) until `bcast` signals completion which (again most likely) won't happen until `processResponse` signals completion which* won't happen until `httpFlow` signals completion which* won't happen until `createRequest` signals completion, which* won't happen until `merge` signals completion.  Because detecting this cycle in general is impossible (consider that there are stages for which completion is entirely dynamic), Akka Streams effectively takes the position that if you want to create a cycle like this, it's on you to determine how to break the cycle.

As you've noticed, `eagerComplete` being true changes this behavior, but since it will complete as soon as any input completes (which in this case will always be the input, thanks to the cycle) `merge` completes and cancels demand on `extractSubtree` (which by itself could (depending on whether the `Broadcast` has `eagerCancel` set) cause the downstream to cancel), which will likely result in at least some elements emitted by `extractSubtree` not getting processed.

If you're absolutely sure that the input completing means that the cycle will eventually dry up, you can use `eagerComplete = false` if you have some means to complete `extractSubtree` once the cycle is dry and the input has completed.  A broad outline (without knowing what, specifically, is in `extractSubtree`) for going about this:

- map everything coming into `extractSubtree` from `bcast` into a `Some` of the input
- prematerialize a `Source.actorRef` to which you can send a `None`, save the  `ActorRef` (which will be the materialized value of this source)
- merge the input with that prematerialized source
- when extracting the subtree, use a `statefulMapConcat` stage to track whether a) a `None` has been seen and b) how many subtrees are pending (initial value 1, add the number of (first generation) children of this node minus 1, i.e. no children subtracts 1); if a `None` has been seen and no subtrees are pending emit a `List(None)`, otherwise emit a `List` of each subtree wrapped in a `Some`
- have a `takeWhile(_.isDefined)`, which will complete once it sees a `None`
- if you have more complex things (e.g. side effects) in `extractSubtrees`, you'll have to figure out where to put them
- before merging the outside input, pass it through a `watchTermination` stage, and in the future callback (on success) send a `None` to the `ActorRef` you got when prematerializing the `Source.actorRef` for `extractSubtrees`.  Thus, when the input completes, `watchTermination` will fire successfully and effectively send a message to `extractSubtrees` to watch for when it's completed the inflight tree.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer - super helpful.  The "endless loop" occurs in a unit test which I finally broke with a `take()` call.  In production, "both ends" of the graph will be connected to a JMS source and sink, respectively.  In production, since the loop is endless anyway, would that eventually cause the graph to deadlock, or is just leaving it as is safe?

Comment: If the source organically never completes, I'd say the stream is intended to run forever (or at least until the program terminates the actor system or gets killed), so not completing isn't a problem.